# How can I get calculated value with different two column on PostgreSQL + Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

here is table

- title
- post_count
- comment_count

I would like to get sum of post_count and comment_count.
What I did is like this, but does not work.

```
.select("count(tables.post_count + tables.comment_count) AS field_name").where("field_name >= ?", 3)
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of what your table looks like, as well as your expected result ?

Comment: for example
summaries table has those columns.

"post_count",  which  is integer, and it has total post count
"comment_count",  which  is integer, and it has total comment count

I want to sum of post_count + comment_count

Comment: I added an answer from what I understood, I'll let you check if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```rb
# Assuming your model is named Table
Table.
  select(:id, 'post_count + comment_count AS field_name').
  where('post_count + comment_count > 3') # Condition you added at the end of your question
```

This would return ActiveRecords with two fields:

- the record id
- the "field_name" column

But I'm not entirely sure this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem stated in your question @esmanbo.